# How to solve the following equation? $\left(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u\right)^{1/u}=\pi ^{1/\pi }$

Tags: closed-form, transcendental-equations

I have no clue:

$$\left(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u\right)^{1/u}=\pi ^{1/\pi }$$

Comment: Can you give some context, or will it not be useful anyway?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $u=\cosh t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $u=\cosh t$ we are left with solving the [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) $~\dfrac t{\cosh t}~=~\dfrac{\ln\pi}\pi$ ,

whose two solutions, unfortunately, cannot even be expressed in terms of the special [Lambert 

 W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The only way forward is with the help of numerical methods, yielding

> $$t_1~=~0.3928615102385430405833389297736055465796116466357\ldots
> \\
> t_2~=~2.6862059675777010426011674393973417566869073839410\ldots$$

corresponding to

> $$u_1~=~1.0781677404428052383937449983538496606471995047941\ldots
> \\
> u_2~=~7.3720141651664644041169505229630376609985273104503\ldots$$

Comment: Just curious ... which algorithm and what type of computer did you use to generate the level of precision you reported herein?  Amazing!

Comment: Newton, Halley, Hoseholder methods work very well for this equation.

Comment: I found interesting that building a $(1,2)$ Pade approximant at $t=0$ gives an approximate solution $t=\frac{\pi -\sqrt{\pi ^2-2 \log ^2(\pi )}}{\log (\pi )}\approx 0.392437$; doing the same at $t=e$ leads to a nightmare which is $\approx 2.68621$.

Comment: This is the hyperbolic [Kepler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) $t=a\cosh(t)$